# Core Location bug? App Delegate never start updating location if I skip initial view controller programatically

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

In my app, I always download async data in app delegate, and when the app arrives to home screen, it checks if that data is downloaded, and pause the main thread while download hasn't finished like this:

```
repeat{
        sleep(1)
    }while asyncData == false
```

The data is downloading in app delegate, in a core location method:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

    //Set coordinates to global var
    let coordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    locValue = coordinates

    setCoordinatesDetails(coordinates)
    if(self.hasBeenLaunched == false){
        self.hasBeenLaunched = true
        loadCitySlugArray()
    }
}
```

This method is mandatory in my app, if this method is never called then the app freeze forever. Since there is no apparent reason that this method won't get called, because the code works, there is a case in it's not getting called, when I try to skip the login page (initial view controller), because the user has already been logged in.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        //Core Location
        // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        //Core Location
        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        userComesFromAppDelegate = true

        //Check if it is first time the user login
        let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("token")
        if(token != nil){
            if ((token as! String).isEmpty == false)
            {
                loginToken = token! as! String
                userIsLogged = true

                //                 SKIP LOGIN PAGE

                self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

                var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let initialViewController : tabBarControler = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarMaster") as! tabBarControler

                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            }
        }

        return true
    }
```

I don't see how I can skip the initial view controller, except doing it this way, so I'm really stuck here, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What if the user disables location services for your app as a privacy option?

Comment: A sleep loop is a horrible technique. You should use something like NSNotification to signal the availability of data.  Also, if you have "always" authorisation then there is no need to ask for "when in use" authorisation

Comment: if the user disables location service for my app then the app won't work because it need user location to display data around him but that's something explained in the initial alert when you launch the app first time